# Socket exception when I install UnityVS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sockets, unity-game-engine, unityvs

I get a socket exception when installing UnityVS

> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
>     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SetSocketOption (SocketOptionLevel optionLevel, SocketOptionName optionName, System.Object optionValue) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at SyntaxTree.VisualStudio.Unity.Messaging.BeaconServer..ctor (SyntaxTree.VisualStudio.Unity.Messaging.UnityProcess process) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at SyntaxTree.VisualStudio.Unity.Bridge.Announcer..cctor () [0x00000] in :0 
>   UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:SetLoadedEditorAssemblies(Assembly[])

What might be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a small bug in UnityVS 1.2. The good news is that it is fixed in 1.8.

This doesn't impact the ability to debug your game.

It simply means that we failed to announce the editor existence over multicast for the remote debugging scenario. Everything local will work just fine.

Comment: And here I was going to mail you to tell you about the new tag I created... of course you have an SO account. ;)

Comment: @Bart, yeah we're often googling for UnityVS, and SO is super well referenced. It was hard to miss those :) Thanks for editing and having a look at the UnityVS questions!